# HTACCESS line preventing loading CSS

Tags: css, .htaccess

Rapid question, I'm using this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which I took from another post and now my CSS file won't show anything.

This is the structure:

```
.
+-- .htaccess
+-- assets
|   +-- style.css
|   +-- images
+-- index.php
```

And there are other files but they're irrelevant.

Comment: You shouldn't take *any* line and just paste it in your environment to see what happens. You should try to write your own. If it doesn't work, then ask for help in SO. This way, you'll learn.

Comment: I get what it does, I just don't get the regex part and how I can fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2 things:

1. No `$` anchor in your regex pattern
2. RewriteCond` to skip existing files and directories

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Also if you are using relative paths for your css/js/images then you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.